# The minimum of 3 columns (phpmyAdmin SQL database)

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin

I have 3 integer columns on the same table that I need to select only the minimum on a select

```
         (price 1) (price 2) (price 3)

 result1:   3           4            5
 result2:   8           1            9
```

.

How I can get only the minimum number of each result?

I work with phpMyAdmin.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
select least('price1','price2','price3') from table1
```

Comment: Maybe I do not explain well, I need a minimum of all three, for example in the case that I have put, in the "result1" the minimum would be "price 1", and "result2" would "price 2"

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`least`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_least) function

```
select result, least (price1,price2,price3) from yourtable
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT LEAST(price1, price2, price3)
FROM Table
```